# Not getting my service injected in Model Binder Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, .net-core-3.1, custom-model-binder

Is there any reason why I'm not getting an injected service into my custom RegisterBinderProvider?

```
            services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                RegisterBinderProvider registerBinderProvider = 
                     DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<RegisterBinderProvider>();
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, registerBinderProvider);
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ApiExceptionFilter));
            });
```

After this code, when I'm in the RegisterBinderProvider class, I see the value of the PasswordHasher service is null. However, I checked the services already injected before inserting the RegisterBinderProvider, and I could find the PasswordHasher in it.

In case you need it, this is my custom BinderProvider:

```
    public class RegisterBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        private readonly IPasswordHasher _passwordHasher;

        public RegisterBinderProvider(IPasswordHasher passwordHasher)
        {
            _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
        }

        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(User))
            {
                return new RegisterBinder(_passwordHasher);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I hope I've provided enough information to understand my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reslove the service in the `GetBinder` method using the `context` parameter:

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
{
        var service = context.Services.GetRequiredService<IPasswordHasher>();
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(User))
        ...
}
```

Since you're only creating a single instance of your `RegisterBinderProvider` and call the `AddMvc` and `ModelBinderProviders.Insert` methods once, it doesn't make much sense to trying to resolve a scoped service at startup.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to change the lifetime from the injected service from scoped to singleton and it worked the way you told me.

Comment: If it's a singleton, you might as well just create an instance of the `PasswordHasher` and inject it manually.

Comment: Why would I do that? I'm also using the `PasswordHasher` in other services with a different lifetime scope and `PasswordHasher` also has a parameter in its constructor.